# Springboard-like scrolling/view switching with snapping on iOS

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Is there a way in cocoa touch to implement view switching behavior like the one in iPhone's springboard? I mean horizontal scrolling with 'snap to view' animation (views are switched only after certain 'scrolling' threshold has been reached)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the ['pagingEnabled' property on UIScrollView](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/pagingEnabled).

Answer (score 2):

SpringBoard, App Store and Mobile Safari use a [`UIPageControl`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html) in conjunction with a `UIScrollView` to provide the little dots you see at the bottom of the screens, that you swipe across with that snap effect.

What views you want to swipe through depends on your application, though, as you're essentially swiping through a `UIScrollView`.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer, but I know it's possible. I have seen this behavior in "Twitter for iPhone" and asked myself the same question.  If you use that app, check out what happens when you swipe the individual tweets to reveal more controls underneath.

This looks like it's part of TableCellView and some touch drag combination. As for the implementation of that... well, im too novice right now.